# how to prove that $\Bbb E(XY) =\Bbb E(X) \Bbb E(Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have to prove that $\Bbb E(XY) =\Bbb E(X) \Bbb E(Y)$, for any pair $X, Y$ of independent random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ which are in $L^1(\Omega)$.

I would say that the claim is the same as saying (since $X, Y$ independent): $\Bbb E[H(X)K(Y)] = \Bbb E[H(X)] \Bbb E[K(Y)]$ for any functions $ H, K:  \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
But...is this really correct? I wouldn't use any actual stuff we're learning, but some stuff we had some weeks ago.

Comment: It's true for measurable $H$ and $K$, but the problem is the same: how do you show this result? What do you know about expectation?

Comment: Fubini's theorem?

Comment: What's your definition of $X$ being independent of $Y$?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a proof:

$$E\left(X\right)E\left(Y\right)=\left(\sum_{x\in X}x\cdot P\left(X=x\right)\right)\left(\sum_{y\in Y}y\cdot P\left(Y=y\right)\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in Y}x\cdot y\cdot P\left(X=x\right)P\left(Y=y\right)$$

Now, since the variable are independent, the last expression becomes:

$$E\left(X\right)E\left(Y\right))=\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in Y}x\cdot y\cdot P\left(X=x\text{ and }Y=y\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{z\in X\cdot Y}z\sum_{xy=z}\cdot P\left(X=x\text{ and }Y=y\right)=\sum_{z\in X\cdot Y}zP(X\cdot Y=z)=E\left(X\cdot Y\right)$$

This is a standart proof for this claim. Now if you are in $L^1(\Omega)$ you just have to change the summations by integrals.

Comment: So you need to change an iterated integral to a double integral via Fubini's theorem, then change that to something involving a sort of convolution, then show that the convolution gives the distribution of the product of two random variables.  Maybe instead of saying "you just have to change the summations to integrals", you should say "you have to change the summations to integrals."

Answer (score 2):

I would say: first prove it when $X$ and $Y$ are indicator functions.  Then prove it when $X$ and $Y$ are finite linear combinations of indicator functions.  Then use definition of $\mathbb E$.  But of course that depends on what your definition of $\mathbb E$ was.  And your definition of $X,Y$ independent (as noted by Stefan).